# Tumblr Main Content Overlapping Fixed Footer

Tags: html, css, tumblr

i'm pretty new to Tumblr and i have added a small bit of code to my Tumblr page to embed a streaming radio station to the page. What i'm trying to do is make the footer overlap the infinite scrolling images/content of the page with a footer 
`<div class='footer'></div>`

In the `<style>`Tag i put:

```
  .footer {
            z-index:-1;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            border-top: thin solid white;
            background-color: #000;
          }
```

How ever the main content still over laps the `<div class='footer'>` i put in.
The footer does indeed remain at the bottom of the page and stretches the full length of the page.

I tried using `z-index: 1;` for the CSS but it still remains the same.

Any idea how to force the Tumblr content behind this DIV so that it scrolls behind it or can i change some of the coding to change the height of the main contents scrolling so it do not reach the bottom of the page?

Comment: Can we see your entire CSS rule? What you're describing seems like it should work as long as you're properly targeting the footer with your CSS.

Comment: In your question you mentioned changing the CSS to `z-index: 1`, yet in your code you have it as `z-index: -1`. Have you tried `z-index: 1`?

Comment: edited the post with the full CSS for the footer which is mostly cosmetics aside from the bottom: and postion: and i did try z-index: 1 as well.

Comment: I wonder if your theme uses a plugin to append posts to the mapge (like infinite scrolling or masonry) in which case this might set the posts to a higher z-index. The best option would be to share a link to your tumblr. Also I would only implement z-index if you absolutely have to.